# Retrieve matching rows using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

This is a simplified version of my problem.

I have table like below

```
Id   Name       SNumber
100  XYZ        123
100  XYZ        123
101  ABC        123
103  QAZ        123
100  XYZ        971
100  XYZ        872
100  XYZ        659
102  PQR        145
102  PQR        707
103  QAZ        421
```

I want to count rows having Snumber as '123' ie **Total** column and rows having Snumber not as '123' i.e. **otherTotal** column

```
Id   Name       Total   OtherTotal
100  XYZ        2           3
101  ABC        1           0
102  PQR        0           2
103  QAZ        1           1
```

What I am doing is using join

```
Select xx.*,otherTotal
From
    ( Select Id,Name,count(*) as Total 
      From  table
      Where Snumber like '123'
      Group By id,name
     )xx

Inner join

     ( Select Id,Name,count(*) as otherTotal
      From  table
      Where Snumber not like '123'
      Group By id,name
     )yy

On xx.Id=yy.Id
```

But this will only return rows if particular `Id` has both `Snumber` as `123` and not as `123`

Data returned is like below

```
Id   Name       Total   OtherTotal
100  XYZ        2           3
103  QAZ        1           1
```

Now there is no guarntee that a particular Id will always have Snumber as 123 so I can't use Left or Right join. How to solve this quagmire ? Giggity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN SNumber = 123 THEN 1 END) Total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN SNumber <> 123 THEN 1 END) OtherTotal
FROM t
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce7a2/1).

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    Id, Name,
    sum(case when SNumber = 123 then 1 else 0 end) as Total,
    sum(case when SNumber <> 123 then 1 else 0 end) as OtherTotal
from Table1
group by Id, Name
order by Id
```

or

```
select
    Id, Name,
    count(*) - count(nullif(SNumber, 123)) as Total,
    count(nullif(SNumber, 123)) as OtherTotal
from Table1
group by Id, Name
order by Id
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2e28/7)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT,   NAME VARCHAR(40), SNUMBER INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES 
(100  ,'XYZ',        123),
(100  ,'XYZ',        123),
(101  ,'ABC',        123),
(103  ,'QAZ',        123),
(100  ,'XYZ',        971),
(100  ,'XYZ',        872),
(100  ,'XYZ',        659),
(102  ,'PQR',        145),
(102  ,'PQR',        707),
(103  ,'QAZ',        421)

SELECT 
    ID, 
    NAME, 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(SNUMBER) FROM @TABLE B
        WHERE 
            SNUMBER = '123' AND A.ID = B.ID
    ) AS TOTAL,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(SNUMBER) FROM @TABLE B
        WHERE 
            SNUMBER <> '123' AND A.ID = B.ID
    ) AS OTHERTOTAL
FROM 
    @TABLE A
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```